# Чи потрібно заміняти слово бутерброд вигаданим новим словом?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/buterbrod) пропонує слово **бутерброд** замінити на слова - *накладець, канапка, мазанець*.

В [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/buterbrod) та [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6190&page=226) присутнє саме слово ***бутерброд***.

> ***БУТЕРБРО́Д***, а, чол. Шматочок хліба з маслом, ковбасою, сиром або
> шинкою чи ікрою.

[Словник іншомовних слів Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53393/279040.html)

> ***БУТЕРБРОД*** (нім. *Butterbrot*, букв. – хліб з маслом) скибка (або дві
> складені) хліба з маслом, сиром, ковбасою тощо.

В СУМ-11 та СУМ-20 присутнє слово *канапка*, але зовсім не відповідає значенню *бутерброд*.

> [Канапка](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanapka)  и, жін. Зменш. до канапа.

Слів *накладець* та *мазанець* в словниках не знайшла.

Чи потрібно заміняти слово ***бутердрод*** вигаданим новим словом? Чи можемо вживати слово ***бутерброд*** у всіх стилях мовлення?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оскільки, це слово фіксують без будь-яких особливих застережень і позначок академічні видання словників, то не думаю, що є потреба замінювати його на питоме українське, бо це слово втратить своє значення). Однак, існує думка, наприклад, [Л. Гнатюк. «Накладанці замість бутерброди. Чому б і ні?»](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine59-25.pdf), що є можливим і ефективним замінити це слово.

Щодо **канапки**, наприклад, то це слово є [діалектизмом](//ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/5115/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0).

[Накладанець](//slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)  знаходимо в Орфографічному словнику, а **мазанця**, справді, немає в словниках.

Отже, **бутерброд** є нормативним для вживання у всіх стилях, а щодо заміни питомо українським словом, то, можливо, вона колись і відбудеться, але зараз, що бачимо на прикладі **накладанця**, вона не дуже «прижилася».